# Deal with independent variables whose value are too concentrated?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, weighted-regression

I'm running a binary classification model with $y_i=0,1$. And independent variables $x_{1i},x_{2i}$.

The problem is that in majority of observations (about 900 out of 1000), $x_{2i}=1$. Due the extreme concentration in $x_2$, do I need to impose some weight on observations with $x_{2i}\ne 1$? Or is there anything else I can do to deal with it?

Comment: Is it causing issues with the model?  I don't see this as a terrible thing necessarily.

Comment: @dsaxton Thanks for reply. I would be great if doing nothing won't affect result. I ran two Logit regressions. First, I include all data, which shows that x_2 is insignificant. Second, I ran the same regression with observation only with x_2 > 1 (I forgot to say that x_2 is always no less than 1). The second regression shows that the impact of x_2 is significant.